# Pass a overloaded function as a template

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

I have this template set

```
        __Self &set(const char *name, lua_CFunction func)
        { return rawSet(name, FuncCall::create(func)); }
....
```

that i use like:

```
.set("child_value", &pugi::xml_node::child_value)
```

But child_value is overloaded with

```
const char_t* xml_node::child_value(const char_t* name) const
const char_t* xml_node::child_value() const
```

and the compiler is giving this error:

```
error C2668: 'SLB::Class<T,W>::set' : ambiguous call to overloaded function
```

How could i fix this error ? I want the child_value() version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define typedefs as:

```
typedef const char_t* (pugi::xml_node::*fn_pchar)(const char_t* name) const;
typedef const char_t* (pugi::xml_node::*fn_void)() const;
```

And then write:

```
//if you want to select first member function that takes parameter (char*)
set("child_value", (fn_pchar)&pugi::xml_node::child_value); 
                  //^^^^^^^^ note this!

//if you want to select second member function that takes no parameter (void)
set("child_value", (fn_void)&pugi::xml_node::child_value); 
                  //^^^^^^^ note this
```

Answer (score 2):

I think an explicit cast is needed:
`.set( "child_value", static_cast<const char_t* (xml_node::*)() const>( &pugi::xml_node::child_value ) );`

Answer (score 0):

OK,
I did it myself.

```
typedef const char* (pugi::xml_node::*ChildValueFunctionType)(void) const; // const required!
ChildValueFunctionType ChildValuePointer = &pugi::xml_node::child_value;
```

Then, just calls

```
.set("child_value", ChildValuePointer)
```